# Qual a lógica necessária para obter as moedas utilizadas em meu algoritmo?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou analisando um algoritmo que retorna o número minímo de moedas a serem utilizadas a partir de um valor em centavos.

```
def numero_moedas(centavos):
    if centavos < 1:
        return 0

    moedas = [50, 25, 10, 5, 1]
    n_moedas = 0

    for moeda in moedas:
        n_moedas += centavos // moeda
        centavos = centavos % moeda
        if centavos == 0:
            break

    return n_moedas
```

Porém, necessito que seja exibida quais foram as moedas utilizadas dentre o número minímo de moedas. Por exemplo:

```
In[1]: numero_moedas(31)
Out[1]: 3, [25, 5, 1]
```

Qual seria a lógica necessária para obter essa lista de moedas utilizadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende da forma que você quer a saída. Se você pretende utilizar um dicionário para associar as moedas com o número necessário, bastaria substituir o `n_moedas`, a lógica é basicamente a mesma:

```py
def numero_moedas(centavos):
    n_moedas_total = 0
    n_cada_moeda = {50: 0, 25: 0, 10: 0, 5: 0, 1: 0}

    if centavos < 1:
        return n_moedas_total, n_cada_moeda

    for moeda in n_cada_moeda:
        n_moedas = centavos // moeda
        centavos = centavos % moeda
        n_moedas_total += n_moedas
        n_cada_moeda[moeda] = n_moedas
        if centavos == 0:
            break

    return n_moedas_total, n_cada_moeda
```

Ou para um resultado mais parecido com o da pergunta, crie uma lista e adicione as moedas contabilizadas no seu loop:

```py
def numero_moedas(centavos):
    n_moedas_total = 0
    moedas_utilizadas = []

    if centavos < 1:
        return n_moedas_total, moedas_utilizadas

    moedas = [50, 25, 10, 5, 1]

    for moeda in moedas:
        n_moedas = centavos // moeda
        centavos = centavos % moeda
        n_moedas_total += n_moedas
        moedas_utilizadas.extend([moeda] * n_moedas)
        if centavos == 0:
            break

    return n_moedas_total, moedas_utilizadas
```

Comment: A ideia era retorna uma lista com apenas as moedas utilizadas, mas acredito que com o dicionário ficou mais facil hehe

Comment: Editei a resposta, talvez esse outro código atenda melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Perfeito! `moedas_utilizadas.extend([moeda] * n_moedas)` era a lógica eu não estava conseguindo. Obrigado!

Comment: Por que nao inciaste com o `n_moedas = 0`?

Comment: @Sidney, não entendi. Eu utilizei `n_moedas` apenas para contar o número de moedas sendo utilizadas dentro do loop, não o total. Mesmo antes de ter editado o código.

Comment: Antes, o `n_moedas` retornava apenas a quantidade min de moedas necessarias. Após sua implementação, o `n_moedas` passou a ser 1. Mas logo vi que implementaste o contador `n_moedas_total += n_moedas`